# Shorten Function with nested If

Tags: excel, vba

I am still trying to learn VBA and am trying to populate a listview based on 3 criterias (a,b, and c).

However, if any of the criterias are left empty, I would like the function to disregard that search criteria. Hence if all criterias are left blank, I would like the listview to be populated with the entire array.

I have tried and came up with this function but felt that this is not the right way as there are too many repetitive code.

Please help if there is any way to shorten this function?

```
function test(usf as userform, a as string, ....., optional b as string, optional c as string)

If a <> "" Then
    For X = 1 To 999
        '-----------------
        'Criteria B
        '-----------------
        If b <> "" Then
            '-----------------
            'Criteria C
            '-----------------
            If c <> "" Then
                If InStr(1, arr(i, 11), a, vbTextCompare) Then
                    If arr(i, 1) = b Then
                        If arr(i, 2) = c Then
                            'populatelistview with criteria a,b,c
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                If InStr(1, arr(i, 11), a, vbTextCompare) Then
                    If arr(i, 1) = b Then
                        If arr(i, 2) = c Then
                            'populatelistview with criteria a & b
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            '-----------------
            'Criteria C
            '-----------------
    
        Else
                If InStr(1, arr(i, 11), a, vbTextCompare) Then
                'populatelistview with criteria a
                End If
        End If
        '-----------------
        'Criteria B
        '-----------------
    Next X
Else
    MsgBox "a is empty"
End If

End function
```

I have also tried with using the wildcard "*" if the criterias are left empty together with if ... like ... for the criterias

However I believe it would create too many unforeseen problems considering that the value in the array might be similar.

& tried with instr as well (but the result would not populate all arrays as it disregards empty array).

Comment: Just my quick help. You can use `Or` or `And` with If statements. For example: `If a <> "" And b <> "" And c <> "" Then`, With that it will make sure all 3 conditions are true before entering the If, otherwise it goes to the Else. You can switch out for `Or` instead of `And` and it will only make sure ONE of the conditions are true. You can also do an `ElseIf` instead of doing a new If statement that way if the first is untrue then it tries the next one. Please note with the And/Or you cannot do `If a And b And c <> "" Then`. Each condition must be separate.

Comment: What are `X` and `i` used for?  You are using `X` for your loop, but `i` in your arrays?  You never set `i` anywhere; this is why [`Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/option-explicit-statement) is so important!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can lose 8 lines by just doing the `If InStr(1, arr(i, 11), a, vbTextCompare) Then`, `If b <> "" Then`, and `If c <> "" Then` checks once each; move them to be immediately *before* you check if the next value is empty or not:  (**n.b.** I have made an assumption here, and changed your `i`s to `X`s, since your loop is on `X`, and you never define `i` anywhere.  The [`Option Explicit` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/option-explicit-statement) can help to uncover a multitude of bugs)

```
function test(usf as userform, a as string, ....., optional b as string, optional c as string)
    If a <> "" Then
        For X = 1 To 999
            If InStr(1, arr(X, 11), a, vbTextCompare) Then
                '-----------------
                'Criteria B
                '-----------------
                If b <> "" Then
                    If arr(X, 1) = b Then
                        '-----------------
                        'Criteria C
                        '-----------------
                        If arr(X, 2) = c Then
                            If c <> "" Then
                                'populatelistview with criteria a,b,c
                            Else
                                'populatelistview with criteria a & b
                            End If
                        End If
                        '-----------------
                        'Criteria C
                        '-----------------
                    End If
                Else
                    'populatelistview with criteria a
                End If
                '-----------------
                'Criteria B
                '-----------------
            End If
        Next X
    Else
        MsgBox "a is empty"
    End If
End function
```

However, you might find it easier to replace `a`, `b`, and `c` with [a `ParamArray` argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-parameter-arrays) that you can check the length of, and use loops to find the first blank.  This will allow you to have as many or as few arguments as you want, without needing to expand the code.

```
Function test(usf as userform, ParamArray Values() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, ParamCount As Long, PopulateCount As Long, X as Long
    If IsMissing(Values) Then
        MsgBox "a is empty"
        Exit Function
    Else
        For i = 0 To uBound(Values) 'How many Parameters do we read?
            If Values(i) = "" Then
                ParamCount = i-1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        If ParamCount < 0 Then
            MsgBox "a is empty"
            Exit Function
        Else
            For X = 1 To 999
                PopulateCount = -1
                For i = 0 to ParamCount 'How many Parameters match?
                    If i=0 Then
                        If InStr(1, arr(X, 11), Values(i), vbTextCompare) Then
                            PopulateCount = i
                        Else
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Else
                        If arr(X, i) = Values(i) Then
                            PopulateCount = i
                        Else
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next i
                If PopulateCount >= 0 Then 'Populate the matched parameters
                    'populatelistview with criteria Values(0) To Values(PopulateCount)
                End If
            Next X
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hey Chronocidal! Thank you very much for a lot of insights from this alone!

1. Thank you for clarifying the X and i, forgot to change the later i into X
2. I believe there'd be an error if using instr with variable that's null, that's why there is the prequalifier.
3. Thank you very much for letting me know that there is ismissing and paramarray! great things to learn!

Comment: The current problem is that:

1. arr(x,i) =/ values (i) as the column actually differs so I alter it with select case and I understand it's from my initial code that could be misleading.
___
2. The listview are supposed to populate the whole row of array of the matched criteria. Example, if a = ID (Compulsory), b = Name (Optional), c = type (optional). So the listview are supposed to be populated with the array arr(x, certainorder) that matched a (ID) if there is no other criteria. But if there are others, It has to ensure that it match with other criterias. How do I do this?